# How to make a symfony form with ajax added fields and DTO?

Tags: symfony-forms, dto

In my view, I have a form that'll allow users to build their own car models. I have a field to choose car-parts and another field to add a color for it. For example, a user can choose "tire"=>"yellow". And there's a button to add new entries to the form.

For generating a form in the controller, I have read many articles on not to bind the entity directly to the form, instead use a DTO (data transfer object) to take care of the validation on the $request first. After a success validation may then have the DTO data pass to the entities.

On submit, my form is going to pass field names like "model_name", "part01", "color01", "part02", "color02" to the controller. From the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/form_collections.html) it shows you how to make it works with the use of the "allow_add" option in the form builder. But here's the problem, that was based on the assumption that you're binding your form with the entities, but how about DTO? How do I put all those data into a DTO and tie it to the form and still able to do the validation?